# Working with specific set of files

Tags: bash

I have a folder that contains log files, all these filenames follow same pattern, the only thing that changes is the date for eg: `Sample_file_20131108.txt` I have a bash script that takes the year, month and date as the input and process the files generated in that particular date.

For eg `./myscript.sh 2011` will process all the scripts generated in the year 2011 `./myscript.sh 201108` will process files generated on the 8th month of the year 2011. I can also specify a certain date as well. This is where I'm stuck, I want to be able to specify a date from 18-25 of a month.  I tried this as the input `myscript.sh 201108{12..25}`but that didn't work. so I'm trying to figure out how to get that into the script.

here is what I have

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
     echo $#
     exit 1
fi

month=$1

#2. Find files of the month to process
LISTFILES=$TEMPDIR/listfiles.txt.$$
echo ''
echo '#2. Finding the files to process'
for i in `find . -name "sample_file*$month*.txt"`
do
echo $i  >> $LISTFILES
done
echo 'done'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `myscript.sh 201108{12..25}` will expand to `myscript.sh 20110812 20110813 20110814 ...` so your script must handle several input arguments, typically with a while loop and the `shift` command.

```
while [[ -n "$1" ]] ; do
  month=$1
  for i in `find . -name "sample_file*$month*.txt"`
  do
    echo $i  >> $LISTFILES
  done
  shift
done
```